# ClassCastException when trying to create Proxy object

Tags: java, proxy, classcastexception, runnable

I'm trying to create a proxy for a given Runnable object using the following code:

```
public class WorkInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    public static Runnable newProxyInstance(Runnable work) 
    {
        return (Runnable)java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            work.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            getInterfacesWithMarker(work),
            new WorkInvocationHandler(work));
    }

    private static Class[] getInterfacesWithMarker(Runnable work)
    {
        List allInterfaces = new ArrayList();

        // add direct interfaces
        allInterfaces.addAll(Arrays.asList(work.getClass().getInterfaces()));

        // add interfaces of super classes
        Class superClass = work.getClass().getSuperclass();
        while (!superClass.equals(Object.class))
        {
          allInterfaces.addAll(Arrays.asList(superClass.getInterfaces()));
          superClass = superClass.getClass().getSuperclass();
        }

        // add marker interface
        allInterfaces.add(IWorkProxy.class);

        return (Class [])allInterfaces.toArray(new Class[allInterfaces.size()]);        
    }
}
```

The proxy should implement all interfaces that the given object implements with the additional marker interface that indicates whether the proxy was already created.
Since I don't know for sure that the given object implements Runnable directly I traverse also on all super classes, however I assume that if it implements another interface that implements Runnable it will work so I don't need to traverse also on interfaces hierarchy.

However, I still get `ClassCastException` when trying to cast the proxy to `Runnable`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy24 incompatible with java.lang.Runnable
```

I'm trying to think what could cause this exception. The class hierarchy of the given object is not available.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try passing desired interfaces directly into invocation of `newProxyInstance()` (i.e. `Array` constructed in place) and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** removed useless code.

This is not the problem, but you should use a `Set<Class<?>>` when you gather all the interfaces because you can get duplicates of the same interface in the hierarchy.

Comment: Correct. In additional tests I did I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: repeated interface: java.lang.Runnable. Using Set solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code to walk the super classes is wrong. Replace

```
superClass = superClass.getClass().getSuperclass();
```

with

```
superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
```

Otherwise you'll quickly take a detour to `java.lang.Class` and then to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Makes sense. so it's actually much simpler than I thought :). Thx